# awk to include name in field between location and average

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below the location `$1` and calculated average `$4` are printed.  I can not seem to get the syntax correct to include $2 in the output between `$1` and `$4`.  Thank you :).

```
awk '{
  if(len==0){
     last=$1;total=$4;len=1;getline
  }
  if($1!=last){
      printf("%s\t%f\n", last, total/len);
      last=$1;total=$4;len=1
  }
  else{
       total+=$4;len+=1
  }
}
END{
  printf("%s\t%f\n", last, total/len)
}' Input.bed > output.txt
```

**Input.bed**

```
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 1   0
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 2   0
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.2 3   0
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.2 4   1
```

**Current output.txt**

```
chr1:955542-955763  21.289593
chr1:957570-957852  304.861702
```

**Desired output.txt**

```
chr1:955542-955763 AGRN:exon.1  21.289593
chr1:957570-957852 AGRN:exon.2  304.861702
```

Maybe

```
awk '{if(len==0){last=$1;**name=$2**,total=$4;len=1;getline}if($1!=last){printf("%s\t%f\n", last, ,**name**, total/len);last=$1;name=$2;total=$4;len=1}else{total+=$4;len+=1}}END{printf("%s\t%f\n", last,**name**, total/len)}' Input.bed > output.txt
```

The input and outputs posted are not real so the #'s don't mean much :)

**Edit:**

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i, $i}' IonXpress_008_150902_4column.bed | head -4
1 chr1:955542-955763
2 AGRN:exon.1
3 1
4 0
```

Comment: How does the input that contains no records with `chr1:957570.957852` produce that in the expected output?  If there are 4 values in column 2, does it matter which of the 4 is printed — first, last, random, drop the suffix?

Comment: in the edit section I added an `awk` to show the fields.  The example iinput and output is not real rather just an example of how the data looks.  Since all of the 4 values make up `$2` they are printed as long as that field is referenced.  I can change the `awk` to print `$2`, but then I loss `$1`.  I hope this helps and thank you :).

Comment: one-liners are highly overrated ;-) ..... But pluse-uno for small sample input, required output and current output!! Good luck.

Comment: @Chris If you learn to use `awk` arrays (hash maps in disguise) it will help you to structure your program better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your key should be a combination of first two fields.  For the sample input you provided

```
$ awk '{k=$1 OFS $2; s[k]+=$4; c[k]++} END{for(i in s) print i, s[i]/c[i]}' file
```

will produce this

```
chr1:955542-955763 AGRN:exon.1 0
chr1:955542-955763 AGRN:exon.2 0.5
```

If field 2 is not part of the key and you want to have the value from the last row for each field 1

```
$ awk '{k=$1; s[k]+=$4; f2[k]=$2; c[k]++} END{for(i in s) print i, f2[i], s[i]/c[i]}' file
```

will produce

```
chr1:955542-955763 AGRN:exon.2 0.25
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am learning `awk` and really appreciate the great tip, very interesting. Thanks again :)